# BeautifulSoup: Find n-th occurence of element

Tags: python, find, beautifulsoup

My html file looks like

```
<li class="fn" id="fn-8">
    <p id="p-53"> Some text
    </p>
</li>
<li class="fn" id="fn-10">
    <p id="p-63"> Some more text
    </p>
</li>
```

and so on. The number of footnote elements varies and the id is not reliable. However, I am interest in the next to last footnote only. I know I can get the number of footnote elements with

```
number_of_footnotes = len(soup.find_all("li", {"class":"fn"}))
```

and that I could iterate through all the occurrences. But is there a more pythonic way to extract precisely one element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using slices to get items in a list.

```
last_item = soup.find_all("li", {"class":"fn"})[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the very next moment I realized that `soup.find_all("li", {"class":"fn"})` returns a list. Hence,

```
list_of_footnotes = soup.find_all("li", {"class":"fn"})
number_of_footnotes = len(soup.find_all("li", {"class":"fn"}))
next_to_last_footnote = list_of_footnotes[number_of_footnotes - 2]
```

delivers my precisely the next-to-last footnote.

It's `-2` instead of `-1` to correct for the fact that Python starts with 0.